# What machine learning algorithm should be used to analyze the relationship between strings?

Tags: neural-networks, ai-design, algorithm

I am trying to build a neural network that takes in a single string, ex: "dog" as an input, and outputs 50 or so related hashtags such as, "#pug, #dogsarelife, #realbff".

I have thought of using a classifier, but because there is going to be millions of hashtags to choose the optimal one from, and millions of possible words from the english dictionary, it is virtually impossible to search up the probability of each

It is going to be learning information from analyzing twitter posts' text, and its hashtags, and find which hashtags goes with what specific words.

Comment: won't simple logic work better? like if the string contains a certain substring then it must refer to a dog...coz i think its impossible for a machine to learn what words might correspond to a dog without seeing it before..like if someone says pug in some other language then human brain has no way of identifying its a dog...its my opinion although...and logical operations will be much faster

Comment: The problem with that is that because I am trying to analyze twitter posts, with hashtags like #follow4follow which are totally unrelated with dogs, I would need a neural network to carry out the decisions. Besides its not going to be only dogs, cats, cars, mountains, calendars, you name it.
Basically it is supposed to work like a translator neural network, translating between "strings" and possible #hashtags
@DuttaA

Comment: That's a NLP problem according to me..and no satisfactory solution exists to NLP..but you might have a case specific solution from experts..lets see

Answer (score 1):

> **Here is a good approach to achieve the task you want:**

**Step 1-** Compute the Vector representation (i.e embeddings) of all the words you want to include. There are many algorithms out there to achieve this task.

[image: Step 1- Compute Embeddings]

**Step 2-** Choose the #words corresponding to your input word (e.g dog) by applying K-Nearest Neighbors (KNN) or similar algorithms. You basically compute the distances using the embeddings.

[image: Step 2 - Apply KNN]

> **Steps Detailed:**

**Step 1-**

In NLP we represent human language as a vector of values instead of a set of characters in order to process it. To do so there are 3 approaches in the literature:

**- Word Level Embeddings:** Represent each word as a vector of values.
   Algorithms: [Word2Vec by Google](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-started-with-word2vec-and-then-how-to-make-it-work-d0a2fca9dad3) ([paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf)), [fastText by Facebook](https://blog.manash.me/how-to-use-pre-trained-word-vectors-from-facebooks-fasttext-a71e6d55f27), [GloVe by Stanford University](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) ([paper](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf)) ...

**- Character Level Embeddings:** Represent each character as a vector of values. Algorithms: [ELMo](https://towardsdatascience.com/elmo-contextual-language-embedding-335de2268604) ([paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.05365)) ...

**- Sentence Level Embeddings:** Represent a sentence as a vector of values. Algorithms: [Universal Sentence Encoder by Google](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1) ([paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.11175)) ...

In your case I suggest to use [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) or [ElMo](https://towardsdatascience.com/elmo-contextual-language-embedding-335de2268604) if you have only words and [Universal Sentence Encoder](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1) if you have words and sentences.  . Compute all your words embeddings and move to the next step.

**Step 2-**

Now that you have your embeddings, compute the distances between all your words *(use Euclidian, Minkowski or any other distance)*. Notice that the computation may take some time but will only be executed once.

Now each time you have a word (e.g dog) you apply the **KNN** algorithm using the computed distances and you will get the most related words to this word.

> **Note**: No need to compute distances and apply KNN if you use Universal Sentence Encoder as the similarity is easily computed using a dot product of the embeddings. See my quick implementation example [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/sentence-similarity-in-python/12232#12232) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Mallet (which uses Gibs Sampling) or gensim LDA (which uses drichlet priors) to model the problem as topics (hashtags) in different documents (tweets).
https://towardsdatascience.com/topic-modeling-and-latent-dirichlet-allocation-in-python-9bf156893c24 has a nice example.

Answer (score 0):

I think your intuition about a classifier being the wrong approach is a good one.  This looks like a great use-case for word vectors, a "self-supervised" learning technique that maps tokens (e.g. "dog") to vectors (which might have anywhere between 50 - 500 dimensions).  Facebook open-sourced a particular excellent tool for training word vectors [called FastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText); you could use this to embed tokens and hashtags alike into a word embedding space.  You should find that the vector for "dog" ends "close to" (small cosine distance).  Given a word, you can easily look up its vector (after training on your corpus, of course), but how to find other vectors that are close to it?  If you want to do better than "brute force" and you need to check against a large number of (vectors for) hashtags, you should consider using [Facebook's excellent FAISS library for fast similarity search](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) to find the closest hashtags.